# How do I allow family members to purchase their own Microsoft points on my Xbox Live family plan?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I pay for a family plan and it has my girlfriend and her sister on it. I would like to know if it is possible to allow them to purchase their own Microsoft points that they can use themselves.

Right now I have to purchase the points and give it to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way they can get points is to purchase them directly from [Microsoft's Xbox website](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Flows/BeginFlow.ashx?workflow=BuyPoints). First it will have the user sign in to their live account. Then they will be able to choose what they would like to purchase and complete the transaction.

This may not be the easiest way, but I am all for prepaid cards. These are available online (Amazon can provide instant codes or mail cards to you, I am sure other companies can do the same) and at retailers nationwide. Once you get the card and have your Xbox turned on and signed in, press the Nexus button and scroll to the left. Select Redeem code and type in the code. They should then have points available to them.

I will make this one comment: I am not on a family plan. However, buying and using points should be the same across all membership options.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Xbox Live Family Pack FAQ](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/JoinLive/FamilyPackFAQ):

*Q: Could a group of friends or roommates share an Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack?*

*A: The Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack is really designed for families. **Only the primary account holder may make purchases against their own billing account**, which is designed to help families better manage their entertainment budget. The primary account holder will also receive Activity Monitoring reports, and have the ability to access online Family Settings for other members in the Family Pack. As a result, the Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack may not work well for groups of friends or roommates.*

So no, they cannot purchase points through the Xbox from the Microsoft store. However, they may purchase a physical points card or points card code from a retailer like Amazon.com, Gamestop, or the Microsoft store (note that one the Microsoft store, there may be permissions that need to be enabled if it is a child account. You'll need to check on that).

*Q: If my child receives a Microsoft Points card as a gift and redeems it on the console, who do the Points belong to?*

*A: **The Microsoft Points would be credited directly to the account of the person redeeming the Microsoft Points card**, in this case your child, as opposed to the primary account holder’s account. If your child were then to purchase a movie or Xbox LIVE Arcade game with his or her points, they would be subtracted from their individual account. Don’t forget that the primary account holder has the option of purchasing and giving Microsoft Points Allowances to other Family Pack members as well.*

Hope this clarifies what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add funds to family members accounts here:

https://account.microsoft.com/family?refd=familysafety.microsoft.com#/settings/add-money/